# Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-2007

Maybe a silly question. Is there a way to run a VSTO Addin in Excel in a client machine running without having VSTO Runtime installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. the VSTO runtime supplies the COM wrappers around IExtensibility2 that is ultimately what Excel exposed for addin functionality.

You have to have Vsto installed for your addin to work in Excel.

However, if your addin dll exports other functions that other apps might use, and they don't involve VSTO, I +think+ you could just drop that dll on a machine without VSTO and it'd still be usable. But again, if it make any use of anything in VSTO, you'd end up needing the VSTO runtime anyway.

And I'm not 100% sure of that, I could easily see VSTO compiling into your dll a quick check for the VSTO runtime and failing to load if it's not there, but I haven't verified that.